# Encuentro indefinido "Undefined type Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens"

Tags: php, laravel, api

[image]

Estoy creando una API con Laravel, tengo el siguiente problema a la hora de implementar laravel/passport. Undefined type 'Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens'.

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y realizar el [tour] para comprender el funcionamiento del sitio. El código debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Ya instale passport:install pero sigue el mismo priblema, estoy trabajando con laravel 7.x

Comment: Por ahora e llegado así:
1. composer require laravel/passport
2. php artisan migrate
3. php artisan passport:install

No se si deba colocar algo en el array de providers del app.php, de momento presento este problema

Answer (score 0):

Agrega:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
```

Comment: Aunque fue algo mínimo, el texto `add` debería estar en español por favor